# Some strange error occurs when manipulating events in the calendar of iOS device

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, ios5, eventkit

I added some events to the calendar and save their eventIdentifier to file. When i want to remove all my events i read the eventIdentifier  from that file to an array and remove each event with its event id. Here is the code to add event to calendar and save their event id to file:

```
  - (void) addEventToCalendar: (id)object
    { 
        @autoreleasepool {    
            int i = 0;
            NSString *string_to_file = @"";
            eventStore=[[EKEventStore alloc] init];
            for(Schedule *sche in scheduleArray){ 

                EKEvent *addEvent=[EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore];
                addEvent.title=sche.course_Name;
                addEvent.startDate = [self stringToDate:sche.from_Date];
                addEvent.endDate = [self stringToDate:sche.thru_Date];
                NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]; 
                [addEvent setCalendar:[eventStore defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
                NSDate *date_alarm = [addEvent.startDate dateByAddingTimeInterval:-(10*60)];  
                addEvent.alarms=[NSArray arrayWithObject:[EKAlarm alarmWithAbsoluteDate:date_alarm]]; 
                NSError *err;
                // do save event to calendar
                [eventStore saveEvent:addEvent span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
                if (err == nil) {
                    NSString* str = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", addEvent.eventIdentifier]; 
                    string_to_file = [string_to_file stringByAppendingString:str];
                    string_to_file = [string_to_file stringByAppendingString:@"\n"];
                    NSLog(@"String %d: %@",i, str);
                }
                else {
                    NSLog(@"Error %@",err);
                }
                i++;
            } 
            // create file to save
            [[NSFileManager defaultManager] createFileAtPath:filePath contents:nil attributes:nil]; 
            inFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForWritingAtPath: filePath]; 
            NSData *data = [string_to_file dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding]; 
            [inFile writeData:data];
        } 
    }
```

And the code below to remove all events i have added to calendar

```
- (void) deleteEventInCalender { 
    filemgr = [NSFileManager defaultManager]; 
    NSString *filePath = [self getFilePath:@"saveeventid.txt"];
    NSFileHandle *inFile; 
    inFile = [NSFileHandle fileHandleForReadingAtPath:filePath];
    NSData *dataFile; 
    dataFile = [inFile readDataToEndOfFile];  
    NSString *tmp =  @"";
    NSString *temp =  @"";
    tmp = [NSString stringWithCharacters:[dataFile bytes] length:[dataFile length]/sizeof(unichar)];
    if(![tmp isEqualToString:@""]){ 
        tmp = [tmp substringFromIndex:1]; 
        event_idArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
        int j = 0;
        while (![tmp isEqualToString:@""]){ 
            int index_find_string = [tmp rangeOfString:@"\n"].location;
            temp = [tmp substringWithRange:NSMakeRange(0, index_find_string)];  
            [event_idArray addObject:temp]; 
            tmp = [tmp substringFromIndex:index_find_string + 1]; 
        }

        EKEventStore* store = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
        j = 0;
        for(NSString *eventid in event_idArray){

            EKEvent* event2 = [store eventWithIdentifier:eventid];
            if (event2 != nil) {
                 NSLog(@"log: %d log id: %@", j, eventid);
                NSError* error = nil;
                // remove event
                [store removeEvent:event2 span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&error];
            }
            j++;
        } 
        [filemgr removeItemAtPath:filePath error:nil]; 
    }
}
```

All codes above work well when i test on the iOS simulator with calendar.sqlitedb. But it makes some strange errors when i run on iPad device 5.0. That is sometime the calendar not remove event or when all events has been remove then after some minutes all events appear again... I don't understand, i don't know why and i very confuse. Does anyone has the same issue with me? Please share your solution!

Added another question: where the calendar database stored in the iOS 5.0 device.

Comment: Did you ever find a solution? I seem to be facing a similar problem...